# Reset Struts2 Token?

Tags: struts2, token, interceptor

I have a token interceptor to block double submitting a form which works great, but I'm looking to reset the token under circumstances.

Essentially what I've got in the page is a list of criteria and a submit button.  When the user clicks the submit button, the criteria is stored as a new row in a specific table in the database.  An ajax call updates the div underneath the form with a succeeded or failed message.  The token works in that I don't want the user attempting to add duplicate rows.  However, if you user changes the criteria (either by choosing a different option in a drop-down menu or editing the text in s:textfield) I want it to reset the token to allow form submission again.  Currently the user has to go back and fill out a new form which is somewhat inconvenient.

I'm using the standard s:token in the .jsp and interceptor lines in struts.xml.  I've been searching for something to reset the token but I haven't found anything.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token is a value in session under `"struts.token"` and in the form as `"struts.token.name"`.

Since you're making an Ajax request underneath the easiest would likely be to set the session token to whatever is already in the form, or to create your own token interceptor (it's quite short, although it uses a static TokenHelper class, which is unfortunate–noted and logged as something to do) that changes the definition of "multiple" submit. (Hash of form vals? Not sure, never given this much thought.)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any answers on google and I don't appear to be getting any answers here so what I did is created a new button called "Clear Form" which calls some javascript to refresh the page and therefore resetting the token and the forms.  Not the most elegant but it works.