# HtttpSession and JSP attribute - not refreshed (Ajax Call)

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I got this code in one of my servlet (Running on App Engine)

```
//get Session
User user = (User)req.getSession(true).getAttribute("user");

//set blob key to user
user.setAvatarBlobKey("new value");
```

This servlet is called through and ajax call.

I got the following code in my jsp

```
<img src="serve?normal=1&blob-key=${user.avatarBlobKey}" width="144" height="144" alt="xxxx" />
```

And when i refresh the page the ${user.avatarBlobKey} is still assigned to the old value but not "new value".

What might be the cause? Could it be due to App Engine?

Comment: The servlet is called  through an ajax call? Are you sure that you are actually accessing the same session that the browser is?

Comment: Oh how can i make sure of that? because i updated the current value in database... so if i log out and log in again it is working, so looks like the session is the same i think

Comment: In each request, the browser sends the session token so the servlet can indentify the right session. If you are doing an ajax call, the browser doesn't send it, you have to somehow send the token yourself. I don't know much about it, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12011202/1073063) has an answer that could give you a clue.

Comment: thank you i will give a look, i was thinking that it will be an easy answer but looks like it's tricky :/

Comment: How exactly are you refreshing the page after the ajax request? Pressing F5 and so on? Or are you talking about a HTML DOM update during processing the ajax response?

Comment: F5, actually i send even the key blob to my webpage and change the target of the url and... that's working perfectly fine, but if i refresh i still get the old one :(

Comment: Apparently something else is setting it back or perhaps browser caching went mad. Put a debug breakpoint on the setter/getter methods and investigate the call stack.

Comment: Yep, my answer was wrong sorry about that. Perhaps something is being catched. Good luck!